# How to call Method DriveMe() or color() only once for all instances in a form application to reduce duplicacy. C#

Tags: c#, button, methods

The form has 4 radiobuttons and 2 buttons. I can select the VehicleType and click button (represent methods) to display the properties of vehicle selected.
I want to call DriveMe() and color() method for all the if else conditions but only one time. Is there any way i can replace IF ELSE to achieve this.

```
namespace vehicles
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public class vehicle
        {
             public string _VehicleType;
            public string VehicleType { get; set; }
            public string Vehiclecolor { get; set; }
           public virtual void DriveMe()
            {              
                MessageBox.Show(VehicleType);               
            }
            public virtual void color()
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Vehiclecolor);
            }
        }
        public class car : vehicle
        {           

        }
        public class truck: vehicle
        {

        }
        public class bike : vehicle
        {

        }
        public class train : vehicle
        {

        }    

       private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                car v = new car();
                v.VehicleType = "Nissan Murano 2007";
                v.DriveMe();
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                truck v = new truck();
                v.VehicleType = "Dodge Truck";
                v.DriveMe();
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
            {
                bike v = new bike();
                v.VehicleType = "Hardley Davidson Bike";
                v.DriveMe();
            }
            else if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
            {
                train v = new train();
                v.VehicleType = "Train";
                v.DriveMe();
            }
            else
            {
                vehicle v = new vehicle();
                v.VehicleType = "Please Select the Vehicle Type";
                v.DriveMe();
            }          
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                car v = new car();
                v.Vehiclecolor = "Black";
                v.color();
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                truck v = new truck();
                v.Vehiclecolor = "White";
                v.color();
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
            {
                bike v = new bike();
                v.Vehiclecolor = "Red";
                v.color();
            }
            else if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
            {
                train v = new train();
                v.Vehiclecolor = "Blue";
                v.color();
            }               
            else
            {
                vehicle v = new vehicle();
                v.Vehiclecolor = "Please Select the Vehicle Type";
                v.color();                
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all of your classes inherit from vehicle you can simplify your code a bit. `DriveMe()` and `color()` are defined on the base class so it's available to all of your more derived classes.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vehicle v = null;

    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        v = new car();
        v.Vehiclecolor = "Black";
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        v = new truck();
        v.Vehiclecolor = "White";
    }
    else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
    {
        v = new bike();
        v.Vehiclecolor = "Red";
    }
    else if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
    {
        v = new train();
        v.Vehiclecolor = "Blue";
    }               
    else
    {
        v = new vehicle();
        v.Vehiclecolor = "Please Select the Vehicle Type";               
    }

    v.color();
}
```

Your other function can be rewritten in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively easy to accomplish using a field:

```
    //First, move the definition of a generic vehicle to a field.
    Vehicle v = null;

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            v = new car();
            v.VehicleType = "Nissan Murano 2007";
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            v = new truck();
            v.VehicleType = "Dodge Truck";
        }
        else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        {
            v = new bike();
            v.VehicleType = "Hardley Davidson Bike";
        }
        else if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        {
            v = new train();
            v.VehicleType = "Train";
        }
        else
        {
            v = new vehicle();
            v.VehicleType = "Please Select the Vehicle Type";
        }          
        v.DriveMe();    //<--- See that it is outside, called once?
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (v == null)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Please select a vehicle first.");
           return;
        }

        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            v.Vehiclecolor = "Black";
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            v.Vehiclecolor = "White";
        }
        else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        {
            v.Vehiclecolor = "Red";
        }
        else if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
        {
            v.Vehiclecolor = "Blue";
        } 
        v.color();    //<-- Also only called once
    }
```

By moving the definition of `v` outside to a class field, its value can be shared with all the instance level methods that the class owns. You can treat any instance like it was a generic `vehicle`.

Comment: He wants to replace the long if else checks

Comment: @EmpereurAiman There are probably clever methods to removing the `if/else` blocks but they would probably be less readable and difficult to understand.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman *"I want to call DriveMe() and color() method for all the if else conditions but only one time"* I didn't read anything in there about replacing the if's, just to call those two methods only once... The last part is "replacing the if...else **to accomplish this**"...

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Vehicle _selectedVehicle;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a vehicle for each radio button:
         Vehicle car = new Car {VehicleType = "Nissan Murano 2007", Vehiclecolor = "Black"Vehiclecolor = "Black"};

         radioButton1.Tag = car;

    }

    private void Selection_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //Subscribe all radio button's Checked change to this event.
      _selectedVehicle = (sender as RadioButton).Tag

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
      if(_selectedVehicle==null)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Select vehicle type");
          return;
        }
        _selectedVehicle.DriveMe();
    }

    }
```